# Kerberos - real world examples?

Tags: security, kerberos

I know how Kerberos works and understand it purpose but I need some real world examples, where does it fit, and have you ever use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Windows 2000 and later use Kerberos as their default authentication
  method. Some Microsoft  additions to
  the Kerberos suite of protocols are
  documented in RFC 3244 "Microsoft
  Windows 2000 Kerberos Change Password
  and Set Password Protocols". RFC 4757
  documents Microsoft's use of the RC4
  cipher. While Microsoft uses the
  Kerberos protocol, it does not use
  the MIT software.
- Many UNIX-like operating systems,
  including FreeBSD, Apple's Mac OS X,
  Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4, Sun's
  Solaris, IBM's AIX, HP's OpenVMS, and
  others, include software for Kerberos
  authentication of users or services.

from wikipedia,

also if you visit http://www.kerberos.org/ , the Kerberos Consortium, they have a pdf document which has as sponsors:

- Apple
- Carnegie Mellon
- Columbia
- Cornell
- Centrify Corporation
- The United States DOD
- Duke University
- The Financial Services Technology
  Consortium
- Google
- Iowa State University
- MIT
- Michigan State
- Microsoft
- NASA
- Pennsylvania State
- Stanford University
- Sun Microsystems
- Team F1, inc.
- The University of Michigan

Which shows that if implemented correctly, there are uses for it.

visit http://k5wiki.kerberos.org/wiki/Main_Page for more information on this consortium.

Answer (score 1):

The computer science department at my university uses it for authenticating users who are logging in to CS dept computers remotely (usually from outside the building or department network) over SSH.

Answer (score 1):

One of the incarnations of the [Integrated windows authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_authentication) is based of Kerberos.

Answer (score 1):

Kerboros is used extensively for authenticated access to AFS. AFS is used a lot in High Energy Physics experiments. Have a look at an [example listing of sites](http://www.central.org/csdb.html) at the openafs.org website. For write access you most probably need a Kerboros token for the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Kerberos is also prefered authentication mechanism by internet explorer in case  it is acting as a client. Basically IE has two options from the server Negotiate/NTLM. If Kerberos fails in first place,then client falls back on kerberos which is default behaviour of IE.

Answer (score 1):

GSSAPI/Kerberos support is built into a wide range of software in the main Linux/Unix platforms today (Debian, Ubuntu, Red Hat, OS X, etc.). Where I work, we have integrated cross-platform authentication among Linux, Solaris, OS X, and Windows, including the following apps:

- Chrome
- IE
- Firefox
- OpenSSH
- PuTTY
- Cyrus IMAP server
- sendmail
- OpenLDAP
- DC LDAP
- Mail.app
- Thunderbird
- Subversion
- NFS
- Samba
- NetApp
- SQL Server
- Apache
- Tomcat

... and others. A single password login on any platform gets you access to all these, including transitively via credential forwarding (e.g. over SSH).